# Values of $a_1$ and $a$ for which $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+(1-2a)a_n+a^2$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to find the values of $a_1$ and $a \in \Re$ that make convergent  the sequence $(a_n)$ defined as:

$a_1 \in \Re $

$a_{n+1} = a_n^2+(1-2a)a_n+a^2$

I can state easily that the sequence is increasing

$a_{n+1} = a_n + (a_n-a)^2 \ge a_n$ obviously, because $(a_n-a)^2 \ge 0$

Now I know that the sequence is increasing, if it happens to be convergent, the limit has to be $a$ because

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n + (a_n-a)^2$$

$$0 = \lim_{n\to \infty} (a_n-a)^2$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = a$$

Now, the sequence

- is increasing
- if it converges, it converges at $a$

As a consequence, if $a_1 > a$ then the sequence diverges.

Now I'm wondering how to prove that the sequence is

- convergent for $a-1\le a_1 \le a$
- divergent for $a_1 \lt a-1$

For the second request, I know it could be something related to $a_2 \gt a$, but I don't know how to proceed from $a_1 \lt a-1$ to $a_2 \gt a$.

Instead, for the first one, I thought it could be convenient to prove by induction that

$$a-1\le a_n \le a \quad \forall n \quad if \quad a-1\le a_1 \le a$$

I can easily get to state that $a_{n+1} \gt a-1$, but I got a few problem with the other hand side.

Comment: Slight quibble: $x^2+2ax+a^2=(x+a)^2$ as opposed to $(x-a)^2$, so $a_{n+1}=a_n+(a_n+a)^2$ and the sequence will converge to $-a$.

Comment: @DavidHill Sorry, I mistyped the sign there, it was a minus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes the proof neater to first simplify the algebraic forms.

Let $x_n=a-a_n$, then $x_{n+1}=x_n(1-x_n)$. If $x_n$ converges, to $ X$ say, then $X=X(1-X)$ and so $X=0$.

**If $x_n<0$**

Then $x_{n+1}=x_n(1-x_n)<x_n$ and so $x_n$ does not converge if $x_1<0$.

**If $x_n>1$**

Then $x_{n+1}=x_n(1-x_n)<0$ and we are in the above case. So $x_n$ does not converge if $x_1>1$.

**If $1\ge x_n\ge 0$**

Then $x_{n+1}=x_n(1-x_n)$ and so $x_n\ge x_{n+1}\ge 0$. Thus we have a non-increasing sequence of terms bounded below. Hence the sequence converges.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

As you said $ (a_n) $ is increasing because

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=(a_n+a)^2\ge 0$$

If it converges to $ L $, we should have

$$L-L=(L+a)^2\implies L=-a$$

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the sign on $a_{n+1} = a_n^2+(1-2a)a_n+a^2$, it should converge to $a$